# How do I get the client name using jquery in a quickbase app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, quickbase

I am trying to modify some jquery/js code in a quickbase app that was build for us. I am trying to use jquery/js to get the client name of a building report we are working on and output it onto a html page. I am able to locate the html for the client name using chrome web developer tool:

```html
<input type="text" size="40" name="_fid_6" id="_fid_6" onblur="OnBF(this)" onfocus="OnFF(this)" value="Test Client">
```

In the html file, I see the following jquery/js lines that will write out information about the building we are writing about but I don't know how to call the input for the client name:

```js
//Fetch Building Information
$.get(urlBuilding,function(rec){
//Get all returned records
    $("record", rec).each(function(j){
        rid  =$(this).find('record_id_').text();
        name  =$(this).find('name').text();
        address  =$(this).find('address').text();
        city  =$(this).find('city').text();
        province  =$(this).find('province').text();
        postal_code  =$(this).find('postal_code').text();
        number_of_units  =$(this).find('number_of_units').text();
        age  =$(this).find('age').text();
        year_of_construction  =$(this).find('year_of_construction').text();
        photo  = $(this).find('photo_embed_tag').text();
        current_rfs = $(this).find('current_rfs').text();

        document.write('<h3>' + name + '</h3>');
        document.write('<table>');
        document.write('<tr><td></td><td>'+photo+'</td></td><td></td></tr>');
        document.write('<tr><td><strong> Address:  </strong></td><td>'+address+'</td><td></td></tr>');
        document.write('<tr><td><strong> City:  </strong></td><td>'+city+'</td></td><td></td></tr>');
        document.write('<tr><td><strong> Province:  </strong></td><td>'+province+'</td></td><td></td></tr>');
        document.write('<tr><td><strong> Postal Code:  </strong></td><td>'+postal_code+'</td></td><td></td></tr>');
        document.write('<tr><td><strong> Units:  </strong></td><td>'+number_of_units+'</td></td><td></td></tr>');
        document.write('<tr><td><strong> Age:  </strong></td><td>'+age+'</td></td><td></td></tr>');
        document.write('<tr><td><strong> Yr of Construction:  </strong></td><td>'+year_of_construction+'</td></td><td></td></tr>');
        document.write('</table>');
    });
```

After looking at the app more, I was thinking maybe I can't get the client name in the building information section because the client name isn't part of the building... there is a section above the code that has looks like this:

```js
//Get the current user's client id
$.get("main?act=API_GetUserInfo",function(xml){
    id = $("user", xml).attr("id");
    email=$("email",xml).text();

    //Set url to query for user's client id
    url="";
    url += "bi3cnb6ep";
    url += "?act=API_DoQuery";
    url += "&query={12.EX.'" + email + "'}&clist=14";
});
```

Comment: Please Paste the code in right format.

Comment: I tried but I can't get the top part above the document.write to out correctly. How do I do it. It's all part of the document.write section - part of javascript..

Comment: Ok. Do you want to get values from input fields ?

Comment: Basically yes. There is an input field for the client name that is built in and I already know how to grab it using jquery with the id. It's this on the console: 
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    $('#_fid_6').val()

But then what?

Comment: store this in variable and use it according to your need

Comment: But following the way the other building information is called i.e. address  =$(this).find('address').text(); why can't I find where the client name variable is stored in the app? I want to be able to just code client_name = =$(this).find('client_name').text();  Can I just add another line with client_name = $('#_fid_6').val() within $("record", rec).each(function(j){...}?